# Cannot reference a variable - cannot find symbol

Tags: java, variables, arraylist, types, reference

I'm making an ArrayList of a type 'Item' that I've created. The class has a variable called `name` to describe the item. The items are stored in an ArrayList.

I cannot figure out how to reference the `name` variable because it is producing an error in the compiler that says `cannot find symbol - variable name.` Specifically, I reference it like this:

```
for (int i=0; i < theMenu.size(); i++) {
                Item temp = theMenu.get(i);
                if(temp.name == keyword)
                    System.out.println("test");
            }
```

I've also tried referencing it like this:

```
for (int i=0; i < theMenu.size(); i++) {
                if(theMenu.get(i).name == keyword)
                    System.out.println("test");
            }
```

It produces the same error. Please help! Here is the relevant code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Doms {

    public static class Item {
        public Item(int itemID, String itemName, double itemPrice, double itemSalePrice, String itemSaleBeginDate, String itemSaleEndDate, ArrayList<Integer> itemReviews, ArrayList<String> itemComments) {
            int id = itemID;
            String name = itemName;
            double price = itemPrice;
            double salePrice = itemSalePrice;
            String SaleBeginDate = itemSaleBeginDate;
            String SaleEndDate = itemSaleEndDate;
            ArrayList<Integer> reviews = itemReviews;
            ArrayList<String> comments = itemComments;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // A list containing each Item and all of its contents
        ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();

        // Create Item elements
        ArrayList<Integer> reviews2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<String> comments2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        Item item2 = new Item(2, "Sour Cream Donut", 1.29, 1.29, "", "", reviews2, comments2);
        items.add(item2);

        //This part doesn't work
        for (int i=0; i < theMenu.size(); i++) {
            Item temp = theMenu.get(i);
            if(temp.name == keyword)
                System.out.println("test");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Class `Item` doesn't have any **fields** (member variables). Your constructor just assigns all the parameters to *local variables*, which won't exist anymore once the constructor returns. Re-read your Java learning guide for how to declare *fields* and assign to them in a constructor. See e.g. [The Java™ Tutorials - Declaring Member Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html) for an example of a class with fields that are assigned in the constructor.

Comment: If you're comparing strings, you need to use equals() rather than ==.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lot going on with your code that needs work, but as suggested in the comments the main issue is that the variable `name` for example doesn't exist in your `Item` class, in fact no variables exist in your `Item` class.

To solve this you need to create class variables that you can reference from elsewhere, note how there are defined directly in the `Item` class not in the `Item(...)` method:

```
public static class Item {
    //Create class variables
    int id;
    String name;
    double price;
    double salePrice;
    String SaleBeginDate;
    String SaleEndDate;
    ArrayList<Integer> reviews;
    ArrayList<String> comments;

    public Item(int itemID, String itemName, double itemPrice, double itemSalePrice, String itemSaleBeginDate, String itemSaleEndDate, ArrayList<Integer> itemReviews, ArrayList<String> itemComments) {
        //Use the values passed into the method and store them as class variables
        id = itemID;
        name = itemName;
        price = itemPrice;
        salePrice = itemSalePrice;
        SaleBeginDate = itemSaleBeginDate;
        SaleEndDate = itemSaleEndDate;
        reviews = itemReviews;
        comments = itemComments;
    }
}
```

Now you can create an `Item` and get the values like normal:

```
//Create an item
Item item1 = new Item(1, "Apple Fritter", 1.49, 1.29, "February 1, 2021", "July 1, 2021", reviews1, comments1);

//Get the public values from the item:
System.out.println("ID: " + item1.id);
System.out.println("Name: " + item1.name);
System.out.println("Price: " + item1.price);
```

And you will get the following output:

```
ID: 1
Name: Apple Fritter
Price: 1.49
```

Note as per the comments to your question you need to use the `String.equals(...)` method to compare strings, you can't compare strings using `==`. For example this is the correct way to compare the name string to the keyword string: `if(temp.name.equals(keyword))`